# Infinite login loop (having tried dozens of solutions)

Tags: nvidia, login

Running Ubuntu 20.04; 2x Geforce GTX 1080 Ti installed.
This is the second time I ever encounter the infinite login loop problem; can't remember how I solved it last time, as it was years ago.
I installed TensorFlow (pip install tensorflow), then following a power outage I couldn't login. I'm guessing the tensorflow installation messed up my nvidia drivers (last version installed: libnvidia-cfg1-460) or something else.
What I've tried so far from tty3:
`$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
change line
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` 
to:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` 
or
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`
or
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"` 
or
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pnpacpi=off"`

Followed by
`sudo update-grub`

Obviously none of these worked.
Then, I've tried purging all CUDA and Nvidia drivers, and attempted to reinstall Nvidia:
`sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` 
`sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda*` 
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Then tried to reinstall from here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local
but got: failed: Network is unreachable (though ping to google works fine)

Of course, still doesn't work. Then, I tried in tty3:
`chown username:username .Xauthority`
but no such file or directory!!
Uninstalled lightdm, then installed gdm3:
`sudo apt-get install gdm3`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`
still, no luck.
Tried again to find .Xauthority
from: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/linux-virtual-delivery-agent/7-15-ltsr/configuration/configure-xauthority.html
`ps aux | grep -i xorg`
got the output:
1323 0.1 0.1 279612 67544 tty1 Sl+ 08:32 0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd -auth /run/user/121/gdm3/Xauthority
(*unforutnately, my screen doesn't show all the output when I'm in tty3, so I'm not absolutely sure about the part between gdm3/ and hority, where the line breaks and I miss several letters on the screen)
so, I try to access /run/user/121/gdm3/ to get .Xauthority:
`cd /run/user`
:No such file or directory

Try step by step:
`cd /run`

That works. Now:

Edited steps inserted here:

`cd user`
`sudo su`
was needed to enter 121:
`cd 121`
`dir`

tells me there's only Xauthority, not .Xauthority. So I tried:
`chown user:user Xauthority`

Still not working. This looks to me like a lost cause, but of course, all and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `cd /user` a typo?  If you are already in `/run` the next part would just be `cd user` without the `/` as that would mean that the `user` folder would be right off the root `/` and not in `/run`.

Comment: Good catch! I managed to enter /run/user, but am then unable to access 121:
cd: 121: permission denied
so I tried sudo cd 121 
cd: command not found

Comment: `cd` is a shell-builtin and not a command, `sudo` only works with commands. Do `sudo su` and then `cd 121`.

Comment: Thank you, was now able to enter folder and run chown user:user Xauthority (not .Xauthority, which doesn't exist). Will report whether this works.

Comment: Try a search of this site for login loop.  The .Xauithority with the wrong permissions is usually in your home directory.  I don't know what you are trying to do with the gdm's copy of Xauthority either.  You should have your own copy under /run/user/1000... Did you try moving all the "dot" files (like .local, .cache, .config, ...) into a directory for temporary storage? If that fixes the login, move them back out one at a time to identify the one that's bad (or just leave them if everything run OK, they'll regenerate).

Comment: I don't have any other Xauthority files on my computer, as seen from the ps aux | grep -i xorg (if I understand it correctly), and definitely not under /run/user/1000

Comment: After you did the edits to `/etc/default/grub` did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Organic Marble: Yes, I forgot to mention and will now edit to add that.
ubfan1: I have no files beginning with a dot under /run/user/1000. All that's there is dbus-1 dconf gnupg gvfs inaccessible pk-debconf-socket pulse snapd-session-agent.socket systemd

Comment: I'm giving up. What's the common practice in this community? Should I delete the question, or leave it for posterity to witness?